# How to push readme.txt into azure container registry for the docker images?

Tags: azure, docker, azure-devops, docker-registry, azure-container-registry

I have created a lot of customized docker images and I have pushed the same into Azure container registry with tags. Now the major problem that the team face is that they are unaware of how to run the docker images (the run command with env/port and volumes) or define the docker-compose files.

Could any let me know if we can attach/push a readme.txt on how to use the image in azure container registry and how to use it?
Please share me code or link on how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

##### Content formats supported in Azure Container Registry

Use a private repository in Azure Container Registry to manage one of the following content formats (at the time of writing).

###### Docker-compatible container images

The following Docker container image formats are supported:

- [Docker Image Manifest V2, Schema 1](https://docs.docker.com/registry/spec/manifest-v2-1/)
- [Docker Image Manifest V2, Schema 2](https://docs.docker.com/registry/spec/manifest-v2-2/) - includes Manifest Lists which allow registries to store [multi-architecture](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-registry/push-multi-architecture-images) images under a single `image:tag` reference

###### OCI images

Azure Container Registry supports images that meet the [Open Container Initiative (OCI) Image Format Specification](https://github.com/opencontainers/image-spec/blob/master/spec.md), including the optional image index specification. Packaging formats include [Singularity Image Format (SIF)](https://github.com/sylabs/sif).

###### OCI artifacts

Azure Container Registry supports the [OCI Distribution Specification](https://github.com/opencontainers/distribution-spec), a vendor-neutral, cloud-agnostic spec to store, share, secure, and deploy container images and other content types (artifacts). The specification allows a registry to store a wide range of artifacts in addition to container images. You use tooling appropriate to the artifact to push and pull artifacts. For examples, see:

- [Push and pull an OCI artifact using an Azure container registry](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-registry/container-registry-oci-artifacts)
- [Push and pull Helm charts to an Azure container registry](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-registry/container-registry-helm-repos)
  To learn more about OCI artifacts, see the [OCI Registry as Storage (ORAS)](https://github.com/deislabs/oras) repo and the [OCI Artifacts](https://github.com/opencontainers/artifacts) repo on GitHub.

###### Helm charts

Azure Container Registry can host repositories for [Helm charts](https://helm.sh/), a packaging format used to quickly manage and deploy applications for Kubernetes. [Helm client](https://docs.helm.sh/using_helm/#installing-helm) version 3 is recommended. See [Push and pull Helm charts to an Azure container registry](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-registry/container-registry-helm-repos).

---

Now to answer your specific question,

You can either masquerade your `readme.txt` file as an **OCI artifact** with single file and push it to the Azure Container Registry and pull from the registry as shown [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-registry/container-registry-oci-artifacts#push-an-artifact) or push the README file as part of a **[Helm Chart structure](https://helm.sh/docs/topics/charts/#chart-license-readme-and-notes)** (if you are pushing a Helm chart to the Azure Container Registry).